# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: When using MVC, MvcReportViewer and Asp.Net aspx page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, reportviewer

I have already a web application in mvc 4. My SSRS reports are available in different server. I am trying to show the report in mvc application. Please find the steps which i followed to show the report.

1. Created a aspx page which contains the report viewer
2. Added the controller in mvc
3. Calling a view page from the controller
4. From the view page i am importing the aspx page using html.partial("aspxpagenamewithoutaspxextension")
5. When i run the action, I am able to see the report with the parmaters.
6. After i chosen the parameters, when i clicked on the submit button i am getting the following javascript error.

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.

Please help me to fix this issue. In case if you need more information this i will give.

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error and once change we made on the RDLC was to set the property `ReportViewer.AsyncRendering=false` and that solved the issue for us. By default the ReportViewer.AsyncRendering is set to true which I believe has dependencies on AJAX controls to do what it needs to do... for that reason we set the rendering to false.

You can probably try that and let me know.

Comment: Hello, mine is already set to false but i see same error. Is there anywhere else to check ?