# Reportviewer giving Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException on IIS

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer, iis-10

I am having RDLC reports with processing mode remote on our server, they are working fine but when I open them programmatically using webforms reportviewer control and scriptmanager it's not working on IIS 10 on our server.

I checked the same code locally and also on my local system IIS they are working fine, there must be some issue with IIS on the server, when I inspect the report, it's giving the following javascript errors, I think scriptmanager when trying to fetch records is giving error as first time reports get the data but when I select any parameter and click view report button again it gives javascript error. Please help.

This issue is only coming on one IIS server, on other server same code is working fine, also tested it on shared server and its working fine, anything wrong with IIS as it was working fine 2 weeks ago.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" >  
            </asp:ScriptManager>
                 <rsweb:ReportViewer  ID="ReportViewer1" KeepSessionAlive="true" AsyncRendering="False" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" Height="100%" Width="100%">      
            <ServerReport DisplayName="" ReportPath="" 
                ReportServerUrl="" />
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

[Error which I am receiving in chrome inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E36tg.png)

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258798/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-when-using-mvc-mvcreportvi)

Comment: @HardcoreGamer I already tried ReportViewer.AsyncRendering=false which is written in above post but its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong happened in code. You can enable failed request tracing to check log of exception.

Add script below the asp:ScriptManager. It will show error message in console. Then analysis the casue of error and fix it.

Usually, an error occurs due a bad piece of code that you have written in code behind section, whick the server refused to accept. Find the bug in your code and fix it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    if (args.get_error() != undefined) {
        var msg;
        msg = args.get_error().message;
        console.log(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the above code and in the console, I am getting the following error which is the same one I added in my post "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500"

Comment: What is the difference between those two servers? You can try to compare the difference between the two. Export the configuration of the server without issue to the sever which cannot work.